# Disable e-checks on Paypal Classic Application?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Some users have found how to abuse e-checks on my application. I have created a new classic api application and under `Adaptive Payments` unchecked `E-Checks`. I have been using that new app for a couple days now and I am still receiving e-check payments. What do I need to do to disable this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an account level flag (meaning you need to do this on the account actually receiving the payment). This thread gives detailed instructions how to do it.

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/My-account-settings-Archive/Disable-eCheck-As-a-Payment-Option/td-p/329394